# Get array with maximum value for each array index

Tags: python, arrays

I am using Python 3 on CentOS 7.  I would like to find the quickest way to get the index of the array with the maximum, for each index with the arrays, over multiple arrays without using loops.  For example, if I input

array[0] = [1,3,9,4,6,8,9]
   array[1] = [2,6,3,8,7,4,5]
   array[2] = [6,3,7,9,1,3,6]

I would like the output to be

```
[2,1,0,2,1,0,0]
```

I tried

```
np.maximum.reduce(array)
```

and got the maximum values, across the arrays, for the indices across arrays.  However, when I tried

```
array.index(np.maximum.reduce(array))
```

I get

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with argmax from numpy

```
np.argmax(array, axis = 1)
```

output

```
[2 3 3]
```

Comment: That worked, except I had to use axis = 0.  Thank very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arr = np.array([[1,3,9,4,6,8,9],
        [2,6,3,8,7,4,5],
        [6,3,7,9,1,3,6]])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

print(df)

result = [df[x].idxmax() for x in df]
print(result)
```